# ui-cropper image not loading

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, crop

I am using [ui-cropper](https://github.com/CrackerakiUA/ui-cropper/blob/master/README.md) directive in my angular project.

I want to crop a selected image from a list of images but for some reason the selected image doesn't appear in the designated area however the cropped part of this selected image does appear but I can't edit the cropping area.

Here is a jsfiddle showing the issue: [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/Hodor_/movobdeL/)

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div>Select an image: <!-- <input type="file" id="fileInput" /> --></div>
  <div class="croparea">
    <ui-cropper image="imageToCrop" result-image="myCroppedImage" area-type="rectangle"></ui-cropper>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="selectImageToCrop()">Select to crop</button>
  <button ng-click="cropIt()">crop it!</button>
  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="image" ng-repeat="item in images">
      <input type="radio" ng-value="item" ng-model="gallery_image.selected" id="{{$index+1}}" ng-change="clearSelect()"/>
      <label for="{{$index+1}}">
        <img ng-src="{{item.url}}">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cropped">Cropped Image:
    <div><img ng-src="{{myCroppedImage}}" /></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app', ['uiCropper'])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myImage='';
    $scope.myCroppedImage='';

    $scope.images = [
      {id:1, url: "https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random=1"},
      {id:2, url: "https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random=2"},
      {id:3, url: "https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random=3"},
      {id:4, url: "https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random=4"}
    ]
    $scope.gallery_image={};
    $scope.gallery_image.selected = {};

    $scope.selectImageToCrop = function(){
        $scope.imageToCrop = $scope.gallery_image.selected.url;
    };
    $scope.clearSelect = function(){
        $scope.imageToCrop = '';
    };
    $scope.cropIt = function(){
        $scope.imageToCrop = $scope.myCroppedImage;
    };

  });
angular.bootstrap(document, ['app', 'uiCropper']);
```

CSS:

```
.croparea {
  background: #E4E4E4;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width:350px;
  min-height:350px;
}
.image-container{
  display: flex;
  .image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
  }
}
```

Any ideas about how to make my image shown for `imageToCrop` parameter in this directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change your css,

```
<div class="croparea">
    <ui-cropper image="imageToCrop" result-image="myCroppedImage" area-type="rectangle"></ui-cropper>
  </div>
```

the `<ui-cropper>` directive rendering image with size from the container of them (height: 100%).

your container `.croparea` have no real **height**.

changing:

```
min-height:350px;
```

to:

```
height:350px;
```

will make the difference.

try to take a look at your working jsfiddle.

Good Luck!